# Как получить значение куки connect.sid при первом запросе?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookie, сессия, express

Мне нужно получить значение connect.sid. Все прекрасно работает, когда эта кука уже установлена - я могу считать её из `req.headers.cookie`. Но при первом запросе, когда сессия только инициализируется, ее там нет. Как  мне получить это значение? Может можно его как-то сделать из `req.sessionID`? Вот код на котором можно попробовать:

```
var express = require('express'),
session = require('express-session'),
cookieParser  = require('cookie-parser'),
app = express();

app.use(session({
    cookie: {
        expires: new Date(Date.now() + 8*60*60*1000),
        maxAge: 8*60*60*1000,
        httpOnly: false,
        path: "/"
    },
    secret: 'secret',
    saveUninitialized: true,
    unset: 'destroy',
    resave: true
}));

app.use(cookieParser('secret'));

app.use('/', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.headers.cookie, res.headers, req.cookies);
    //При первом запросе - undefined, undefined, {}
    try{
        var t = req.headers.cookie.split('=');
        var c_sid = t[t.indexOf('connect.sid') + 1].split(';')[0];
        console.log('connect.sid', c_sid);
        res.end(c_sid);
    }catch(e){
        res.json(e);
    }
});

app.listen(80);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Порывшись в коде модуля `express-session`, нашел, как этот самый `connect.sid` генерируется:

```
var connectsid = 's.'+req.sessionID+'.'+crypto.createHmac('sha256', secret)
                 .update(req.sessionID).digest('base64').replace(/\=+$/, '');
```

Где secret - тот secret, который вы указываете в options сессии.